# Mailman default mailman@ list?

Tags: debian, mailman

Does Mailman usually have a default mailman@yourdomain list? We recently set up a new instance of Mailman on our new server and it seems to have one by default, but all it gets is spam from other websites' mailman@ lists, and I'm not sure where it came from. Working on Debian Lenny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a default list setup for all of the monthly password spam^Wreminders that get sent out, and some other (rare) administrative e-mails.  It's been created by default on all new installs for at least the last couple of years.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It seems to be collecting spam only, and I don't think I've seen it send any of the password reminders, but the server hasn't been up for a full month yet.